# pythonic way of making list of list using nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list

```
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'g', 'h', ['i', 'j', 'k']]]
```

is there any way how do I get a result like this using python

```
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
          ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'j'],
          ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [
      [
        'a', 
        'b', 
        'c', 
        ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
        'g', 'h', 
        ['i', 'j', 'k']
      ]
    ]
l = l[0]
final = []
count = 0

while count <= 2:
    result = []
    for i in l:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            result.append(i)
        else:
            result.append(i[count])
    count += 1
    final.append(result)

print(final)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'j'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k']]
```

Then you can assign `final` to `mylist` if you like.

**Explanation**

The first assignment assigns the list you provided to `l`, then remove the extra nested list.

Then we define some variables, and we have a nested loop. Count variable is for counting the d, e, f and i, j, k iterations, the inner for loop appends a, b, c, g, h to `result` and also one of d,e,f and i,j,k. On second iteration it will be e,j, third will be f,k, appending the `result` list to `final` list on each `while` loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer except this scales to longer nested lists.

```py
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'g', 'h', ['i', 'j', 'k']]]

counter = 0
tempmylist = []
newmylist = []
nestedlistlength = 0

while True:
    for i in mylist[0]:
        if type(i) == list:
            if len(i) > nestedlistlength:
                nestedlistlength = len(i)
            try:
                tempmylist.append(i[counter])
            except:
                continue
        else:
            tempmylist.append(i)
    newmylist.append(tempmylist)
    tempmylist = []
    counter += 1
    if counter == nestedlistlength:
        break

print(newmylist)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'i'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'j'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'k']]
```